# Why are formal lienar combinations defined as functions in Lee's book on smooth manifolds but not in the book Geometry by Tu?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I am trying to understand the definition of formal lienar combinations. I have found two definitions:

From Geometry by Tu:
[image]

From Smooth Manifolds by Lee:

[image]

**Question**

Tu's definition makes sense to me. The second definition is a bit of a mystery to me.

- Why is it defined in terms of functions?
- What would the the linear combination look like. Is it by any chance $f(S):=Im(f)$?
- Is the second definition a generalisation/abstraction of a property of $\sum r_{i}(v_{i},w_{i})$.
- In Lang's Algebra book it says that $r_{i}(v_{i},w_{i})$ can be viewed as $\delta_{(v_{i},w_{i})}$. Why is $(v_{i},w_{i})$ viewed in one case as a function and in the other as $(v_{i},w_{i})\in V\times W$? Or is $(v_{i},w_{i})$ identified with $\delta_{(v_{i},w_{i})}$?

Comment: For example, if $S=\{s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots\}$ then a map $f:S\mapsto \mathbb R$ which maps $s_1\mapsto r_1, s_2\mapsto r_2, s_3\mapsto r_3$ and $s\mapsto 0$ whenever $s\ne s_1, s_2, s_3$ can be viewed as a (finite!) "linear combination" $r_1s_1+r_2s_2+r_3s_3$. Adding those "linear combinations" or multiplying them with a scalar just adds all "coefficients"/multiplies them with a scalar, which amounts to, in effect, adding those functions/multiplying *them* with a scalar.